# What is wrong with my C selection sort code below? what should I do in my void selection sort

Tags: c

so this is the command, create an array of structs (a total of 15 elements) consisting of variables of type int and string. sort the array and perform a search on the array based on one of the elements with a variable of type int. use straight selection sort and interpolation search. i'm very new on learning Selection Sort, please correct the code below, I've reached my limit.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>

void swap(int *xp, int *yp) {
int temp = *xp;
*xp = *yp;
*yp = temp;
}

void selectionSort(int angka[], int n) {
int i, j, k;

for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {
    k = i;
    for (j = i+1 ; j < n; j++) {
        if (angka[j] < angka[k]);
        k = j;
    }
    swap(&angka[k], &angka[i]);
  }
} 

void printArray(int angka[], int size) {
int i;
for (i=0; i < size; i++) {
    printf("%d", angka[i]);
}
printf("\n");
}

struct dat {
int angka;
const char* name;
};

int main () {

struct dat nama_var[15];
nama_var[0].angka = 4;
nama_var[0].name = "Farina";
nama_var[1].angka = 12;
nama_var[1].name = "Rima";
nama_var[2].angka = 7;
nama_var[2].name = "Jihan";
nama_var[3].angka = 1;
nama_var[3].name = "Audi";
nama_var[4].angka = 14;
nama_var[4].name = "Tantri";
nama_var[5].angka = 5;
nama_var[5].name = "Farhan";
nama_var[6].angka = 15;
nama_var[6].name = "Tedi";
nama_var[7].angka = 6;
nama_var[7].name = "Husain";
nama_var[8].angka = 9;
nama_var[8].name = "Laudia";
nama_var[9].angka = 13;
nama_var[9].name = "Sari";
nama_var[10].angka = 2;
nama_var[10].name = "Ardi";
nama_var[11].angka = 10;
nama_var[11].name = "10";
nama_var[12].angka = 8;
nama_var[12].name = "Johan";
nama_var[13].angka = 11;
nama_var[13].name = "Misbah";
nama_var[14].angka = 3;
nama_var[14].name = "CIndy";
```

I'm stuck about the code here

```
int n = sizeof(nama_var.angka)/sizeof(nama_var.angka[]); 
selectionSort(nama_var[15], n);
printf("Sorted : \n");
printArray(angka, n);
getch();
}
```

Comment: This question's shown code fails to meet Stackoverflow's requirements for showing a [mre]. Because of that it's unlikely that anyone here can conclusively answer the question; but only guess at the most. You need to [edit] your question to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that everyone else can cut/paste ***exactly as shown***, compile, run, and reproduce the described issue (the "reproducible" part, this includes any ancillary information, like any input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Comment: In `selectionSort(nama_var[15], n);` the `nama_var[15]` part is a bug. You are attempting to pass the single element that is one past the end of the array. Also you declared `void selectionSort(int angka[], int n) {` with the first parameter an array of integers. Not an array of `struct dat`

Answer (score 3):

In your `nama_var` array you have names and integers and you want to sort the array based on the integers, however you made a function that sorts an array of integers. Let's change your function a bit so it sorts structs instead :

```
void selectionSort(struct dat names[], int n);
void swap(struct dat *xp, struct dat *yp); /* struct dat *temp = *xp; */
```

You want to sort the structures according to their `angka` value, so you have to extract them from the structures in order to compare them :

```
if (angka[j] < angka[k])
```

becomes :

```
if (names[j].angka < names[i].angka)
```

Finaly I think you made two typos, the if statement was bypassed each time : a single semicolon is a valid statement in C.

```
for (j = i+1 ; j < n; j++) {
    if (angka[j] < angka[k]) /* ; <---- */
        k = j;
}
```

And you call the function which is supposed to take an array but by putting square brackets you are giving the element at index 15 (which is outside the array) :

```
selectionSort(nama_var[15], n);
```

What you were trying to do was :

```
selectionSort(nama_var, n);
```

Comment: Yeah, I will edit with what other have answered.